# Check User is registered or not in Django 2.0

Tags: python, django

Currently, the admin(superuser) is creating the users and sending the details along with reset password link to the users through email. The user will click on the reset password link and change there password.

Now the admin must know whether the user has logged in to the system after resetting the password. The Admin must be notified as user active(user logged in) or inactive(user not logged in yet).

I am new to Django and don't know how to determine whether the user has logged in or not.

**After Ralf suggestion this is how my code looks**
I have assigned a default value as False to is_register and in html is shows inactive. After the user logs in the inactive status must be changed to active.

*models.py*

```
class RegisterUser(models.Model):
    #user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=None)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default =True)
    is_register = models.NullBooleanField(_('register'), default=False, null=True)
    program = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Test')
```

*vews.py*

```
@login_required
def users(request):
    re = RegisterUser
    registeredUsers = User.objects.all()
    reg = User.last_login
    if reg is not None:
        re.is_register = False
    else:
        re.is_register = True
    return render(request, 'account/viewUsers.html', {'registeredUsers' : registeredUsers,
                                                      'reg' : reg })
```

*user.html*

```
 {% for RegisteredUser in RegisteredUsers %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ RegisteredUser.first_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ RegisteredUser.last_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ RegisteredUser.email }}</td>
        {% if RegisteredUser.is_active %}
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled>Active</button></td>
        {% else %}
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled>Inactive</button></td>
        {% endif %}
        {% if RegisterUser.is_register %}
           <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled>Active</button></td>
        {% else %}
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled>Inactive</button></td>
        {% endif %}
```

I still see the register as inactive on html page though the user has logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Django `User` model has a `DateTimeField` called [`last_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login).

You could use this field to obtain the infromation you need. 
After the superuser creates a user through the admin panel, the field `last_login` will be `None` until there is a successful login done.

So, `User.objects.filter(last_login__isnull=True)` gives you all created users that never logged-in.

---

After the edit to the question:

- First of all, you probably should just use djangos default `User` model instead of your own, because the fields you suggested are practically the same that already exist.
- The line `reg = User.last_login` is not correct, because the field `last_login` should be checked for each user instance, not for the class object.

Try this instead in your view:

```
@login_required
def users(request):
    return render(
        request,
        'account/viewUsers.html',
        {'all_users': User.objects.all()})
```

And this in your template:

```
{% for u in all_users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ u.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ u.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ u.email }}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled>
                {% if u.is_active %}Active{% else %}Inactive{% endif %}
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled>
            {% if u.last_login is None %}
                Never logged in
            {% else %}
                Has last logged in on {{ u.last_login }}
            {% endif %}
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have edited my question with the code. Could you please have a look and help me